# Multiple Arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml, web-services, xsd

I have beginner skills only for php,

I need to get several persons information `name` and `surname`, currentlt i get only one.

Problem described below, that's more accurate: 
current php code fragment:

```
myRegister($server,'info',array(
'in' => array('id_code' => 'xsd:int'),
'out' => array(
    'name' => 'xsd:string', 
'surname'=>'xsd:string', )));
```

current result:

```
<Response>
    <name>Name</name>
    <surname>Surname</surname>
</Response>
```

what I need:

```
<Response>
    <person>
       <name>Name</name>
       <surname>Surname</surname>
    </person>
</Response>
```

How to write php a multiple arrays? with php ? as I see in this case i can recieve several persons

Comment: Is it works this whay ? 

<Response>
    <person>
       <name>Name</name>
       <surname>Surname</surname>
    </person>
</Response>

'<Response>
    <person>
       <name>Name</name>
       <surname>Surname</surname>
    </person>
</Response>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
    myRegister($server,'info',array(
'in' => array('id_code' => 'xsd:int'),
'out' => array('person' => array(
    'name' => 'xsd:string', 
'surname'=>'xsd:string', ))));
```

i'm not an expert, maybe this can be helped

Answer (score -1):

```
array( 'person' => 
   array( 
      array( 'name' => 'john', 'surname' => 'smith' ),
      array( 'name' => 'jack', 'surname' => 'black' ),
      ...
   )
);
```

In php non associative arrays can not have named nodes as in xml so every element of 'person' array myst be translated in to a  node. As far as I am aware (and please correct me if i am wrong) this can only be done via custom function.